# Calling a function with (id)sender from another class not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, ibaction

I'm trying to call a function that has `(id)sender` from a different class using:

```
    -(IBAction) runAgainButton:(id)sender {
        ViewControllerName *instance = [[ViewControllerName alloc] init];
        [instance startFunctionName:nil];
    }
```

but the function will not execute. '`startFunctionName`' is located in Class1.m and I'm trying to call it in Class2.m.  Other people have suggested passing `nil` in for the `(id)sender` in other articles but it hasn't worked for me, I can't figure out what else should be substituted for `nil` for the `(id)sender`.
'`startFunctionName`' is supposed to create a camera view controller to start scanning barcodes using the front facing camera. The first time this function is called in the `Class1ViewController` (after pressing a button), the camera loads perfectly fine and scans what I need it to. After scanning, it will load `Class2ViewController` and that where I have the issue with '`runAgainButton`'. '`runAgainButton`' is associated with a button in the app.  When I click on that button, it should run the '`startFunction`' again by opening the camera view controller to start scanning barcodes. I would just copy the code for '`startFunctionName`' to work in the other class but it's 300+ lines of code.  If anyone knows what's going on here and could help me out, that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Well allocating a *local* view controller won't get you very far; what do you think will happen to the view controller instance when that method returns?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
ViewControllerName *instance = [[ViewControllerName alloc] init];
```

Here, you are creating a completely new and independent instance of the ViewControllerName class. But that is the *the wrong instance*. There must *already* be an instance of this class somewhere in your view controller hierarchy, and *that* is the instance you want to talk to.

Comment: How would I talk to that instance then?

Comment: You have to know where it is in the view controller hierarchy and get a reference to it. It's such an interesting problem that much of a chapter of my book is devoted to it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_visibility_by_relationship

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a reference from your first viewController to the second and store it as a variable then call it directly or create a public method depending on it's usage.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "GoToSecond" {
        var secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
        secondViewController.firstViewController = self 
    }
}
```

Then in your secondViewController you can call that method directly from the previous instance.

```
self.firstViewController.runAgainButton()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a property

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) Class1ViewController *class1VC;
   ```

   in class 'Class2ViewController.h'
2. Declare your ibaction method in 'Class1ViewController.h'

   ```
   - (IBAction)startFunctionName: (id) sender;
   ```

   and define this method as usually in 'Class1ViewController.m' file.
3. Now when you navigate from 'Class1ViewController' to 'Class2ViewController', then fill the property as:

   ```
   class2Object.class1VC = self;
   ```

   where 'class2Object' is the instance of class 'Class2ViewController'
4. And in class 'Class2ViewController', where you have defined the method

   ```
    -(IBAction) runAgainButton:(id)sender
   {
       [self.class1VC startFunctionName:nil];
   }
   ```

   where 'self.class1VC' contains the instance of class 'Class2ViewController'
5. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Your solution is an interesting option and I might explore it some more, but as it is right now and with implementing it in my program, it doesn't work.  It actually breaks my project.  I appreciate the effort though.